# Installing Google Earth Enterprise - "Error While Loading Shared Libraries: Libcap.so.1" Can Not Open Shared Object File: No Such File or Directory"

Tags: suse

Hello stack overflow!!!

I'm installing Google Earth Enterprise on a Suse 11.1 Linux machine.  I have installed GEEFusion and GEESever, and both installs worked correctly, in theory.  (In fact, when I do a command line run of server it starts up perfectly.)

However, when I try to start up GEEFusion using /etc/init.d/gefusion start I get the following error:

> Error While Loading Shared Libraries: Libcap.so.1" Can Not Open Shared Object File: No Such File or Directory

We went and downloaded the library pack and installed it on Suse, and it still gives that error.  We chmod'd the library items to 755 and it still gives that error.  We also tried to install this on fedora and it still gave this error.

We're really at a loss of what to do, we have a ticket into Google but time is running short!  Anyone seen this error?  Suggestions?

Comment: Had the same problem on SUSE. I ran `zypper install libcap` and then had to run `zypper install  libpng12-0` after which I could start fusion. Maybe this helps you too.